# How can we know if a number (x_ is divisible by n unequal parts

Tags: discrete-mathematics

For example, let us take x = 360, and n = 4
Now, 
360 can be divided in 4 unequal parts as  88,89,91,92
therefore my answer here could be yes.
Another example would be if x = 360 and n = 358;
now there is simply no way to divide 360 in 358 unequal numbers, what I am looking for here is a simple mathematical relation, if at all possible.

Comment: Are you requiring the "unequal numbers" to be positive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimum sum of $n$ unequal numbers is $T_n=\frac 12n(n+1)$, the $n^{th}$ triangular number.  For your example, with $n=4, T_n=1+2+3+4=\frac 12\cdot 4 \cdot 5=10$.  Any number $x \ge 10$ can be expressed as the sum of $4$ unequal parts-just take $1,2,3,x-6$.  We need $x \ge 10$ so that $x-6 \gt 3$ is distinct from the others.

In general, you need $x \ge \frac 12n(n+1)$